# Product List with grid layout and other element in between

Tags: html, css, list, grid, grid-layout

I want to create a product list with grid layout where it is possible to display another element in between the list. The products of the list are added in a shop cms dynamically through a for loop so in the html I have to put the other element before or after the forloop. I tried with a autoplacement for the products but than the other element is displayed at the end of the list. How can I achieve to display the "other" element in the second grid row that it fills the third and the fouth grid column.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#grid-table {
  display: grid;
  width: 90%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  list-style: none;
  gap: 15px;
}
.red-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.green-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="grid-table">
    <!--- dynamically added through for loop -->
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <!--- for loop ends -->
    <li class="green-box"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While I can see how you can place the green square in the second row third column, I don't quite understand how it is to span column 3 and 4 as it has a fixed width. Or do you want it placed centrally sort of between and slightly overlapping those two columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by this way, but we need to change the fixed width of `.green-box` as it's supposed to span from column 3 to column 4.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#grid-table {
  display: grid;
  width: 90%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  list-style: none;
  gap: 15px;
}

.red-box {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.green-box {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="grid-table">
    <!--- dynamically added through for loop -->
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <li class="red-box"></li>
    <!--- for loop ends -->
    <li class="green-box"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```